# Composer + PhantomJS: Why is the class not found?

Tags: php, phantomjs, composer-php, php-phantomjs

I am trying to install [PHP PhantomJS package](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/) in a blank project, but I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client' not found
```

This is my composer.json:

[image]

And this is my index.php:

[image]

Can anyone tell why is the class not found? I suspect something is wrong in composer.json but I cannot figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is not found, because the `index.php` misses to include the Composer Autoloader.

Please add the following line at the top:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

(I wonder why you are working directly inside the `JonnyW/PhantomJS` project folder and not inside your own project? Anyway...)

Comment: You are right, ma bad! I fixed it the same day! Thanks tho